# Twitter API returning error 220

Tags: php, twitter

Using this PHP library: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

```
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth(OAUTH_TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_TWITTER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);  
$access_token = $twitteroauth->getAccessToken($_GET['oauth_verifier']);
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token; 
$user_info = $twitteroauth->get('account/verify_credentials');
```

*Sometimes* it returns error code 220

```
object(stdClass)#58 (1) {
    ["errors"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#59 (2) {
            ["message"]=> string(53) "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource"
            ["code"]=> int(220)
        }
    }
 }
```

The strange thing is that sometimes it works fine. Also, it never happened with twitter API v1. It only started after updating to v1.1.

The app is not trying to perform any action on behalf of the user, nor trying to obtain any info like timeline or list of friends. It is just trying to authenticate the user.

When giving error 220 I log the `@_SESSION` and I get this:

**#1** Sometimes gives this

```
array(4) {
    ["oauth_token"]=> string(40) "SOME_RANDOM_STR_THAT_LOOKS_LIKE_A_TOKEN"
    ["oauth_token_secret"]=> string(41) "SOME_RANDOM_STR_THAT_LOOKS_LIKE_A_SECRETE_TOKEN"
    ["access_token"]=> array(1) {
        ["Invalid request token"]=> string(0) ""
    }
    [...] => array(...) {"OTHER_DATA_RELATED_TO_MY_WEBAPP"}
}
```

**#2** And sometimes this

```
array(5) {
    ["oauth_token"]=> string(41) "xxxxxxxxx" 
    ["oauth_token_secret"]=> string(41) "xxxxxxxxxx"
    ["access_token"]=> array(8) {
            [string(144) ""1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> Invalid / expired Token /oauth/access_token?oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            ["oauth_nonce"]=> string(32) "xxxxxxxxx"
            ["oauth_signature"]=> string(28) "xxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
            ["oauth_signature_method"]=> string(9) "HMAC-SHA1" 
            ["oauth_timestamp"]=> string(10) "1388026884"
            ["oauth_token"]=> string(41) "xxxxxxxxx"
            ["oauth_verifier"]=> string(42) "xxxxxxxx"
            ["oauth_version"]=> string(22) "1.0 "
    }
    [...] => array(...) {"OTHER_DATA_RELATED_TO_MY_WEBAPP"}
    ["User"]=> array(7) {"ALSO_RELATED_TO_MY_WEBAPP"}
}
```

On this #2 scenario, `User` has the info of that user on the app, and it actually has info like twitter ID and avatar on twitter. This means that that user has once logged in with twitter perfectly, the webapp created an account for him/her, but he/she is now falling into this 220 error.